# Rails generators :: colorize output and raise exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I’m currently writing more or less sophisticated rails [generator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html). It’s quite straightforward, save for a lack of documentation. I see that internal methods (came from `Thor`, AFAIU,) like `create_file` and others colorize their output:

[image: create: app/policies/application_policy.rb]

On the other hand, I could not find any appearance of the code handling this colorization during my quick-walk-through open source generators (like `rails`-default, `pundit`, `devise`, etc.) I expect this functionality to be exported, smth like `say WARN, 'You are doing it wrong'`.

Another minor question: is it indeed necessary to handle all the errors manually, print out a message and gracefully exit instead of raising some kind of rails-generators-aware standard exception?!

Any suggestions on what am I missing are strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while there was a silence, I managed to implement color logging myself. In case any stranger in the future would require the same functionality, I just drop it here.

```
SYMBOLS = { 
  scs: ['107', '✔'], 
  nfo: ['68', '✓'], 
  wrn: ['226', '✗'], 
  err: ['196', '✘'] 
}
def log msg
  sym = SYMBOLS[caller(0)[1][/`(\w+)'/, 1].to_sym]
  puts "\e[01;38;05;#{sym.first}m#{sym.last} #{generator.name}\e[0m: #{msg}"
end

def err msg
  log "#{msg}\nAborting...\n\n"
  exit 1
end

def nfo msg ; log msg ; end
def scs msg ; log msg ; end
def wrn msg ; log msg ; end
private_method :log
```